# Set distance from top page with "WrapStyle.Through" set

Tags: .net, migradoc

I have a TextFrame (BlueWorkOrderLine) (and also an Image) with "WrapStyle.Through" set in the Primary Header. I want to position it "40" from the top edge of the page.

Neither ".Top" or ".DistanceTop" seems to work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Everything seems to line up the way I expect.

[image]

```
public static Document CreateWorkOrderPDF2(Document document, string filename, string WorkOrderHeader, string myMessage)
    {
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter;

        section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;

        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 40;
        //Sets the height of the top margin
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 100;
        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 40;
        section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 40;

        /*HeaderFooter
         *************/
        HeaderFooter header = section.Headers.Primary;
        header.Format.Font.Size = 16;
        header.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;
        header.AddParagraph();

        /*Logo Image
         ***********/
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image headerImage = header.AddImage("../../Fonts/castorgate.regular.png");
        headerImage.Width = "2cm";
        headerImage.Top = 100;
        headerImage.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = 200;
        headerImage.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        /*Blue Work Order Line
        **********************/
        TextFrame BlueWorkOrderLine = header.AddTextFrame();
        BlueWorkOrderLine.Top = 40;
        BlueWorkOrderLine.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = 40;
        BlueWorkOrderLine.Left = 0;
        BlueWorkOrderLine.Width = 300;
        BlueWorkOrderLine.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;


        Paragraph headerParagraph = BlueWorkOrderLine.AddParagraph(WorkOrderHeader);
        headerParagraph.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";
        headerParagraph.Format.Font.Color = Colors.Blue;
        headerParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;


        /*Vertical Text TextFrame
        *************************/
        TextFrame WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame = header.AddTextFrame();
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Orientation = TextOrientation.Downward;
        //moves text to the right
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Left = 550;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Width = 10;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Top = 0;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Height = 150;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        Paragraph WorkOrderVerticalParagraph = WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.AddParagraph();
        //Paragraph WorkOrderVerticalParagraph = header.AddParagraph();
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 8;
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.AddText(WorkOrderHeader);
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;



        //BODY PARAGRAPH
        Paragraph EstRecordsParagraph = section.AddParagraph(myMessage);
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 10;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkRed;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.RightIndent = 0;

        Paragraph renderDate = section.AddParagraph();
        renderDate = section.AddParagraph("Work Order Generated: ");
        renderDate.AddDateField();

        return document;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand all position options of TextFrames, so this is just a guess. Maybe you have to set `RelativeVertical` or one of the other options to get the desired effect.

Sample code:

```
var tf = section.AddTextFrame();
tf.Width = "190mm";
tf.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
tf.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
tf.MarginTop = "230mm";
```